# Import Excel file to ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have student table with some feilds and I want export excel file format that student table in asp.net after export i will  change some data feilds  to excel  and import that excel file to asp.net. If I will change data to excel means after import excel file that changes want update to student table in sql server

Comment: You could use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) for reading the excel file.

Comment: Why export from a database to excel, update excel and then update a database? Why would you not just select from database, update data, import/update target table directly.

Answer (score 1):

[LINQ-to-Excel](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel#welcome-to-the-linqtoexcel-project) to read an excel file. I have not used this personally, but it does look promising.

Use [DoddleReport](http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2011/12/07/Transform-your-LINQ-queries-into-ExcelPDF-reports-with-DoddleReport-1.aspx) to create excel files from LINQ generated data.

Comment: I have used it a fair amount. Excellent tool for the job. You can install it using Nuget. Just be sure to install the correct one (x86 or x64) based on the access engine installed on your server.